# Convert columns of a list to rows in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
val = [1, 2, 3, 8, 5]
wavg = [1.77,
        2.52,
        2.52,
        6.095,
        6.095 ]
```

I have to subtract  `1 - 1.77, 2 - 2.52, 3 - 2.52, 8 - 6.095, 5 - 6.095`

When I use `demeaned=[i - j for i,j in zip(val,wavg)]` I am getting wrong results because the dimensions are not equal. Can you please suggest how to convert wavg list to `[1.77, 2.52, 2.52, 6.095, 6.095]`.

Comment: Is `wavg` a numpy array?

Comment: You switch variable names, leaving an undefined `v`.  Your question doesn't make sense, since Python lists do not have the inherent direction you show.  In fact, changing `v1` to `val` gives you code that computes the desired differences.

Comment: By v I mean val. The answer currently is wrong. Instead of subtracting like this 1-1.77,2 -2.52,3-2.52,8-6.095,5-6.095 currently just the first value 1 is subtracted from each of the values in wavg.

Comment: Well, if they are not numpy arrays, I can't reproduce your problem in Python 3.5.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your given code doesn't run (undefined variable); when repaired, it doesn't exhibit the problem you describe.

Comment: Btw, why would `1` be subtracted from each value in wavg? You subtract `val-wavg`.

Comment: `wavg` already is `[1.77,2.52,2.52,6.095,6.095]`. Try `wavg == [1.77,2.52,2.52,6.095,6.095]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, one of the below solutions are what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

val = np.array([1, 2, 3, 8, 5])
wavg = np.array([[1.77],
                [2.52],
                [2.52],
                [6.095],
                [6.095]])

diff1 = val - wavg.T
diff2 = val - wavg.ravel()
diff3 = np.array([i-j for i, j in zip(val, wavg)]).T

assert (diff1 == diff2).all()
assert (diff1 == diff3).all()
```

Comment: I tried this. (v is a list in my function with [1, 2, 3, 8, 5])                        wavg_trans = np.array([wavg])
  val= np.array([v])
  diff1 = val - wavg_trans.T. But I am getting the error                   
     wavg_trans = np.array([wavg])
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 1

Answer (score 1):

If these are numpy arrays (rather than lists, as you show), then simply use `wavg.T`, the transpose.

Comment: These are not numpy arrays. Just lists.

Comment: See my comment on the question: your formatting worry makes no sense, because there is no "direction" on a list.  There's no such thing as changing a 1-D list between horizontal and vertical format.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(val)):
    val[i] = val[i] - wavg[i]
```

Comment: How do you know, that the OP wants to replace `val`?

Comment: Does it matter?
he can use a new list if he doesn't want to replace